# Evaluation metrics multi-class classification (ROC- PR curves)

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Facing with a multi-class classification task,

my question is:

are **ROC** and **Precision-Recall** (One-vs-All-Rest) curves useful to evaluate and visualize the performance of a model? 
or **Confusion matrix**, **Precision**, **Recall**, **F-score** (micro and macro) are enough?

What do you think about?